# Bitcoin fork BTC and BCH

Tags: blockchain-fork

BTC holders received 1 BCH for each BTC during the fork in August. How will be the case in November? Will BTC holders and BCH holders receive 0.5 new coin for each BTC and BCH?

Answer (score 4):

The potential fork in November does not affect the BCH-chain at all.
Since the new coin does not have a name yet, I will just call it **BFC** for now.

If you have 1 **BTC** now you will have 1 **BTC** and 1 **BFC** in November.
If you have 1 **BCH** now you will have 1 **BCH** and 0 **BFC** in November.
If you have 1 **BTC** and 1 **BCH** now you will have 1 **BTC**, 1 **BCH** and 1 **BFC** in November.

Nobody knows if the new BFC coin will stay like BCH or if nobody supports it (= nobody mines it, it's worth nothing, not listed in any exchanges, ...).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have "a" BTC and "b" BCC, you'll  have "b" BCC, while having "a" coins on both new chains. Your BCC amount won't change.

Comment: Will a new type of cryptocurrency be created in November, or not? In order to get new coins, should I hold bitcoin or bitcoin cash now?